# Corner points of a RegularPolygon?

Tags: graphics

For a given regular polygon(simple example)

```
poly=RegularPolygon[{0.5 , 0.7}, 1, 5]
```

I would like to know, how to calculate the cornerpoints!

Thanks!

Comment: `RegionBoundary[poly] /. Line[p_] :> p`?

Comment: @cvgmt Clever! Thank you

Comment: consider also `CirclePoints @@ poly`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
reg = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 2}]]
MeshCoordinates[RegionBoundary[reg]]
```

> `{{0.634779, -0.777161}, {0.579052, -0.624394}, {-0.517278, -0.868522}, {-0.207988, 0.400948}}`

Answer (score 10):

## Method 1

```
PolygonCoordinates[RegularPolygon[{0.5, 0.7}, 1, 6]]
```

## Method 2

```
MeshPrimitives[RegularPolygon[{0.5, 0.7}, 1, 6], 0]
```

## Method 3

```
CirclePoints[{0.5, 0.7}, 1, 6]
```

Comment: Didn't think at MeshPrimitives! Thanks, very helpful.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann So you chose another. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can get the points directly with [`CirclePoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePoints.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

poly = RegularPolygon[{0.5, 0.7}, 1, 5];

pts = poly /. RegularPolygon :> CirclePoints

(* {{1.08779, -0.109017}, {1.45106, 1.00902}, {0.5, 1.7}, 
    {-0.451057, 1.00902}, {-0.0877853, -0.109017}} *)

pts == Most[RegionBoundary[poly] /. Line[p_] :> p]

(* True *)

SeedRandom[1234];

poly2 = RegularPolygon[RandomReal[5, 2], RandomReal[10], 
   RandomInteger[{3, 15}]];

pts2 = poly2 /. RegularPolygon :> CirclePoints

(* {{4.67794, 1.79959}, {5.12976, 2.1787}, {5.23218, 2.75955}, 
    {4.93728, 3.27033}, {4.38304, 3.47206}, {3.82881, 3.27033}, 
    {3.53391, 2.75955}, {3.63633, 2.1787}, {4.08814, 1.79959}} *)

pts2 == Most[RegionBoundary[poly2] /. Line[p_] :> p]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
MeshCoordinates@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@RegularPolygon[{0.5, 0.7}, 1, 5]
```